# Why is a duplicate object being added to my Python set when it shouldn't be?

Tags: python, set

I have a class definition of this:

```
class Question:
    title = ""
    answer = ""
    def __init__(self, title, answer):
            self.title = title
            self.answer = answer
    def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.title == other.title and self.answer == other.answer
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(repr(self))
```

and I'm trying to add many of these objects to a set, only if the object does not have the same properties as any of the other objects already in the set:

```
        questionset = set()
        q = Question(questionparts[0] + questionparts[1], questionparts[2])
        if q not in questionset:
            questionset.add(q)
```

If I have two questions, each with the same property values, I expect only one to get added to my set, instead my set has a length of 2.

What am I doing wrong? If I log each question object, I can confirm the items have the same property values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your hash function is *grossly* ineffective. Python requires that your `__hash__` function should return the same value for two objects that are considered equal, but yours doesn't. From the [`object.__hash__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value

`repr(self)` returns the default representation, which uses the *object id*. It'll basically return a different hash based on *object identity*. You may as well have done:

```
return hash(id(self))
```

That's not a good hash as that values differs between all instances. As a result your `hash()` values fail to meet the required property:

```
>>> a = Question('foo', 'bar')
>>> b = Question('foo', 'bar')
>>> a == b
True
>>> hash(a) == hash(b)
False
```

You need to hash your attributes instead:

```
return hash(self.title + self.answer)
```

Now the hash is based on the same values that inform equality.

Comment: This is what I get for being a python noob and coding at 3AM. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for `__hash__` says:

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value

Your class does not meet this requirement.  Since you don't override `__repr__`, `repr(self)` will use the default behavior, which will give you something like `<Question object at 0x00001234>`.  This means every `Question` instance will have a different hash value --- even instances that compare equal.

You need to rewrite your `__hash__` to be compatible with your `__eq__`.  If you're comparing on title/answer equality, the simplest solution is to also hash the object's title and answer, for instance by returning `hash((self.title, self.answer))`.

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn Pieters and BrenBarn have mentioned, your `__hash__()` method doesn't work because of the behaviour of the default `__repr__()` method. Their answers show alternate implementations of `__hash__()`; the code below instead implements a simple but useful `__repr__()`.

I'm *not* claiming that my approach is *better* than Martijn's or BrenBarn's approach. I'm simply showing that your original `__hash__()` method will work once your class has a suitable `__repr__()` method.

FWIW, it's generally a good idea to implement a `__repr__()` method for your classes. Even if you don't actually need the method in your final production code it can be helpful for testing purposes while developing the code.

I'm running this on Python 2.6.6, hence the `from __future__ import` and the explicit inheritance from `object`; you don't need to do those things in Python 3, but the code should still function properly on Python 3 as is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, title, answer):
        self.title = title
        self.answer = answer

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Q({s.title!r}, {s.answer!r})'.format(s=self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.title == other.title and self.answer == other.answer

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(repr(self))

questionset = set()

q1 = Question('2+2', '4')
q2 = Question('2+2', '4')
q3 = Question('2*2', '4')

print(q1, q2, q3)
print(q1 == q2, q1 == q3)

questionset.update((q1, q2, q3))
print(questionset)

questionset.add(Question('1+3', '4'))
questionset.add(Question('2+3', '5'))
questionset.add(Question('2*3', '6'))
questionset.add(Question('1+3', '4'))
print(questionset)
```

**output**

```
Q('2+2', '4') Q('2+2', '4') Q('2*2', '4')
True False
set([Q('2+2', '4'), Q('2*2', '4')])
set([Q('2+3', '5'), Q('2+2', '4'), Q('1+3', '4'), Q('2*3', '6'), Q('2*2', '4')])
```

Note that there's no need to test if a `Question` instance is already a member of `questionset`. Set elements are unique, so it's impossible to add the same element multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You are hashing the object instead of the value(s). Try to hash `self.title+self.answer` instead of hashing `self`